# Post to Php file using Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am posting to PHP file an OBJECT, the question is, I am not using name="" like when we do it inside the forms, but Instead, I am posting an Object, look:

```
    const done = async obj => {
    console.log("sending JSON to PHP...");
     await fetch("myFile.php",
        {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(obj)
        }
    )
}
let obj = {
    email: "ahmad@example.com",
    message: "salam"
}
const send = async (obj)=>{
    let response = await done(obj);
}
send(obj);
```

The question is, How the PHP will resolve the posted arguments?

here is what I've tried:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

but as usual, this isn't working.

[EDIT]:

Extra question: is it important to send the POSTED data as JSON format? Is it important to do that while using the fetch API?

Comment: Please do not reply with Jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($body , true);

$email = $data['email'];
$message = $data['message'];
```

Comment: I'm unable to understand? could you please explain for me?

Comment: i have updated the answer, i don't know how to make it simpler then that

Answer (score 2):

As you have used stringify, your php file will receive a string representation of your json object. So you will have to use json_decode to convert the string to a php object.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
$email = $data->email;
```

Further clarification:
If the request body contains string representation of JSON, content-type header will be text/plain, even if the Content-Type is set to application/json. So, in php file, you will have to read the raw text in body with file_get_content first as string and the convert it to php json object.

Comment: I tried to do:
$email = json_decode($_POST['email']);
$message = json_decode($_POST['message']);
but it didn't work.

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: I am getting this error

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: email in /opt/lampp/htdocs/file.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined index: message in /opt/lampp/htdocs/file.php on line 9

Comment: I have added code in answer.

Comment: Thanks for help, could you please explain the first line a little bit?

Comment: The first line gets the raw data from request body.

Comment: See reference here on how to set the request body https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request#Parameters

Comment: @mathew if this resolves your issue, please accept the answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, I think that this solution was about to fix the problem, but unfortunately not this time, I am getting "" empty, nothing after doing:


$request_body_raw_data = file_get_contents('php://input');

$data = json_decode($request_body_raw_data , true); // because it's coming as json from javascript


$email = isset($data['email']);

$message = isset($data['message']);

Comment: Oh, sorry for placing this inside the comment.

Comment: I've added isset function because I am getting this warning from PHP:
Trying to access array offset on value of type null in ...

Comment: You have introduced a different error with isset().  You need to use if or ternary operator with isset(). Use var_dump($data); to check what is inside the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216852/discussion-between-smartdroid-and-mathew).

Comment: Yes, that worked, 
but one thing is that we should use true as the second argument of the json_decode function to make sure that it will return an array